# skia/buildtools/linux64/gn: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found

Tags: centos, skia

I try to compile the library skia on a CentOS 7 machine. But when calling `gn`, I get this error message

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found
```

According to a quick search on Google, there is no way to get `GLIB_2.18` on CentOS 7. But then, how can I build the library skia on a CentOS 7 machine?

Comment: Seems you got a GN for a later OS. You can build "a CentOS 7 **gn** " : `git clone https://gn.googlesource.com/gn`

Comment: My gn build : `gn-bin-1.el7.x86_64.tar.xz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A-WrV65GbGlyBVSQnSseNau1JRjqn8hN/view?usp=sharing ..... Uninstall the alien package (gn), and copy the new executable  `gn` to /usr/local/bin/